# Implementing OData with custom DAL

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

We have a custom (.NET/SQL based) DAL and would like to expose OData capabilities.

In the first instance we are just interested in allowing simple querying of the data, but will later want to allow updates, and i guess there will be security issues to think about. Ultimately we're looking at "Apps" and using something like JayData/Breeze to manage the communication.

We have a rich set of metadata which allows us to attach calculated columns to our datasources which can then be retrieved from our DAL as if they are DB columns.

We do not use EF at all. How do we start exposing the data via OData? We are heavily invested in our DAL which works perfectly for all our Windows based applications. Implementing IQueryable sounds like a monumental task. Should we use WCF services or Web API?

This article looks like a good start, I'm thinking we can maybe get the ODataQueryOptions and reinterpret that into something our DAL can work with.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/02/25/translating-odata-queries-to-hql.aspx

There's not much documentation on any of this though and I'm reluctant to get started without checking there's not an easier alternative i've just missed.

Comment: The example you have listed is a good starting point, I wanted more control and ended up having to write my own version of ODataQueryOptions to handle things like $inlinecount, $filter and also $select.

Comment: Thanks. Are you just parsing the raw OData query? Are you using WebAPI? What reference documentation did you use? BTW I think the latest build of OData in WebAPI handles $select and $filter, you can get useful info back in ODataQueryOptions - I'm just lacking a good resource for all the various properties MSDN is fairly lacking.

Comment: You can see what I did here - [MicroLite.Extensions.WebApi](https://github.com/TrevorPilley/MicroLite.Extensions.WebApi). I based the object names and structures on the ASP.NET ones so that I could swap back to that if it gets to the point where it supports everything I need. I used used the details in the webpage you already listed and the example NHibernate provider on codeplex to create mine.

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this you are looking for?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg601461.aspx

Best regards
db

Comment: I think that would require an `IQueryable` which the OP has stated that they don't have.